# Почему WinMain должна использовать __stdcall?

Tags: c++, winapi

у меня возник вопрос почему точка входа в `WinApi` должна иметь соглашение о вызове `__stdcall`? Я знаю, что при разных соглашениях о вызовах по разному управляется стек, а так же функции имеют разные идентификаторы, но мне все равно не понятно почему это именно так? Какова техническая причина данного правила, если она есть? Заранее спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: Так случилось исторические, подходит?

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо) Я то думал там какая-то причина по типу неправильной  очистки стека или тому подобное, а тут все так просто.

Comment: Вот только WinMain() в C++ имеет соглашение __cdecl. Имели ввиду WinApi в заголовке?

Comment: @LShadow77, извините не совсем вас понял, в каком смысле "в заголовке"? И разве WinMain в С++ - __cdecl, вроде бы всегда перед ее объявлением пишут макрос WINAPI, который потом расширяется в __stdcall

Comment: Очевидно потому, что и все остальные функции WINAPI используют это соглашение о вызовах.

Comment: @n 1 k z z z 9 сорян, я ошибся. WinMain() действительно имеет тип вызова WINAPI (он же APIENTRY). Давно её не объявлял руками, вот и подзабыл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я писал - краткий ответ - так случилось.

Полный чуточку интереснее. Многие думают, что main/WinMain - это и есть точка входа в программу. Но это не так в большинстве случаев. На самом деле эта функция вызывается далеко не самой первой. Вначале запускается CRT (он же RunTime, он же стартовый код, и ещё много названий). Этот код инициализирует статические переменные, подготавливает окружение (тот же `cin`/`cout`), а по выходу с `main` производит обратный процесс, вызывает всякие [atexit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/atexit?view=msvc-160).

И понятно, что весь этот код рассчитывает на какие-то соглашения, говоря другим языком "API". Но почему именно `__stdcall`,  а не какой то другой? а все очень просто. Какое то соглашение нужно было обязательно. И какое же возьмем? правильно, наше, которое мы для себя сделали и везде в WinAPI используем - [__stdcall](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=msvc-160)

> The __stdcall calling convention is used **to call Win32 API functions**. The callee cleans the stack, so the compiler makes vararg functions __cdecl. Functions that use this calling convention **require a function prototype**. The __stdcall modifier is **Microsoft-specific**.

(выделения мои)

Ещё на почитать https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-160